# How to automatically inline included files in C?

Tags: c

I am using a third-party C file that has a segment below.

```
static void
random_vector(gsl_vector * v, gsl_rng * r)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < v->size; ++i)
    {
      double vi = __x0 * gsl_rng_uniform(r) - __x1; /* in [-1,1] */
      gsl_vector_set(v, i, vi);
    }
}

#include "test_impulse.c"
#include "test_gaussian.c"
#include "test_median.c"
#include "test_rmedian.c"
```

Is there a way, e.g. a gcc option,  to *automatically* transform the original C file into one that has the "test_impulse.c", etc. included? 
Doing this manually would be easy, but I will have to deal with a lot of such cases.

[UPDATE] Because the C file also include some header files (.h files), which I would not need to put in the transformed file. Thus, using the gcc "-E" option, as suggested in the comments below,  would not be okay.

Comment: The `-E` option probably does what you want. The `-P` option is sometimes an alternative.

Comment: Maybe `gcc -E`? See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html

Comment: If the "included" C files shall be used in other C modules, I think a better way is to create a library the contains the now-included C modules. In this way you may link your code with a library without including C-modules inside your C code.

Comment: To make it clear: Do you want to have the result of preprocessor or do you only want to include the files without touching macros etc.?

Comment: @Gerhardh I would need the result of preprocessor, but not touching the header files.

Comment: The preprocessor would also replace macros that are used in these headers.

Comment: Given your update, you have some serious misconceptions about how the preprocessor works, and how/when to include files. What are you *trying to do* here? Are you trying to combine translation units, or to link them together?

Comment: Suppose `test_impulse.c` contains `#include <stdio.h>`; do you want the contents of `<stdio.h>` in the output?  It isn't all that hard to produce a script that handles one level of `#include` for `.c` files, leaving macros unexpanded and (nested) headers (as opposed to source code in `.c` files) unincluded.  It's not trivial, but it isn't all that hard.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution has a few caveats but in general when all the lines have `#` as first character and end in `c"` and no line starts with `$` you could have a little pipeline which could look like this:

```
sed -E 's/^#(.*[^c]")$/$\1/' ORIGINAL | \
gcc -E - | \
sed -E 's/^\$(.*)$/#\1/' > FINAL
```

What this does is, it replaces the hashtag with a dollar sign on all lines that start with a hashtag and end with `c"`. Then it executes `gcc -E` and then reverts all dollar signs to hashtags.

Comment: Thanks. I like the simplicity in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be a small C program that executes the inclusion the .c files.

The advantage is that it can be easily adapted (e.g. if you want to move the embedded .c files to another location, etc.).

A simple C program for a *NIX operating system might look like the following code, presumably it needs some slight customization for your specific use case.

As always with such operations, make a backup of the input before applying the program!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <libgen.h>


#define MAX_LINE 2048

void exit_with_error(const char *msg);
void backup(const char *filename);
void process(char *filename);
void include(char *filename, FILE *fpout, regmatch_t *pmatch, char *line);
void copy(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout);
FILE *input_file(const char *input_file_name, const char *mode);
FILE *backup_file(const char *input_file_name, const char *mode);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: incl <file.c>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    backup(argv[1]);
    process(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

void exit_with_error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void process(char *filename) {
    FILE *fpin = backup_file(filename, "r");
    FILE *fpout = input_file(filename, "w");

    regex_t regex;
    char msgbuf[100];
    regmatch_t pmatch[2];

    int rc_comp = regcomp(&regex, "^#include[ \\t]+\"([a-zA-Z0-9_\\/]+\\.c)\"[ \t]*[\r\n]?$", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (rc_comp) {
        regerror(rc_comp, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "regcomp failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = MAX_LINE;
    while((getline(&line, &len, fpin)) != -1) {
        int rc_exec = regexec(&regex, line, 2, pmatch, 0);
        switch (rc_exec) {
            case 0: {
                include(filename, fpout, pmatch, line);
                break;
            }
            case REG_NOMATCH:
                if(fputs(line, fpout) == EOF) {
                    exit_with_error("writing output failed");
                }
                break;
            default:
                regerror(rc_exec, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "regexec failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    regfree(&regex);
    free(line);
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);

}

void include(char *filename, FILE *fpout, regmatch_t *pmatch, char *line) {
    char *match = calloc(pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so + 1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(match, line + pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so);
    fprintf(fpout, "// -- %s --\n", match);
    char *include_file_name = malloc(strlen(dirname(filename)) + sizeof(char) + strlen(match) + 1);
    strcpy(include_file_name, dirname(filename));
    strcat(include_file_name, "/");
    strcat(include_file_name, match);
    FILE *fp_include = input_file(include_file_name, "r");
    copy(fp_include, fpout);
    fclose(fp_include);
    fputs("\n", fpout); //make sure to add newline in case it is missing in the .c
    free(match);
    free(include_file_name);
}

void copy(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = MAX_LINE;
    while((getline(&line, &len, fpin)) != -1) {
        if(fputs(line, fpout) == EOF) {
            exit_with_error("writing output failed");
        }
    }
    free(line);
}


void backup(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fpin = input_file(filename, "r");
    FILE *fpout = backup_file(filename, "w");
    copy(fpin, fpout);
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
}

FILE *input_file(const char *input_file_name, const char *mode) {
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(input_file_name, mode)) == NULL) {
        exit_with_error("problem with input file");
    }
    return fp;
}

FILE *backup_file(const char *input_file_name, const char *mode) {
    char *bak = malloc(strlen(input_file_name) + strlen(".bak") + 1);
    strcpy(bak, input_file_name);
    strcat(bak, ".bak");
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(bak, mode)) == NULL) {
        exit_with_error("problem with backup file");
    }
    free(bak);
    return fp;
}
```